# What's the name of this set design?

Tags: chess-set

I'm looking to buy a nice wooden set and board, something I've wanted for a long time. I have this Kasparov vs Karpov picture as my desktop background [image: Kasparov vs Karpov]

and I love the set, but I can't find one quite like it. Does anyone know the name of this style of set, or where I could get one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Tony Rotella on [the reddit page I pointed to this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/64tk5n/can_anyone_help_me_identify_what_kinddesign_of/dg4yk32/):

> They're DGT "Timeless" pieces: http://www.digitalgametechnology.com/index.php/products/eboard-chess-sets
>   This has been a very standard FIDE design for a long time, though there have been slight modifications over the years to (at the least) the pawns and bishops I believe.
>   You might also be interested in these, which are basically the same: http://www.houseofstaunton.com/the-championship-series-chess-set-3-75-king.html